# htaccess redirect wildcard /folder1 folder2... /folder* to new url help needed

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, hyperlink, wildcard, html

How does one redirect all 47 links (and all subfolders, contents) in one line of code in the .htaccess file

For example:

http://www.africanafrican.com/PhotoAlbum(1 thru 46)/

to

http://www.ramanujanramanujan.com/PhotoAlbum(1 thru 46)

where PhotoAlbum(1 thru 46) are PhotoAlbum, PhotoAlbum1, ..., PhotoAlbum46

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \www\.africanafrican\.com$
RewriteRule ^PhotoAlbum\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.ramanujanramanujan\.com\/PhotoAlbum\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

this is what i have so far but I can not figure out the wildcard. I cannot do the backslash so it shows up as a

Answer (score 0):

you don't want those backslashes, since you have nothing that you need to escape except for the `.`'s. This is all you need:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?africanafrican\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^PhotoAlbum(.*)$ http://www.ramanujanramanujan.com/PhotoAlbum$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: another question if the folde name is more than one word what do i do for example www.ramanujanramanujan.com/black history imagery/ and in a subfolder www.ramanujanramanujan.com/negroartist/black history imagery/